# Odoo - Check if the user has a group

Tags: python, odoo-9

If a **user** doesn't have the **group** "base.group_user", how can I display a **warning** ???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

to check if the use has a group_base try this :

```
if self.env.user.has_group('base.group_user') :
    base_group = self.env.ref('base.group_user');
    raise exceptions.ValidationError('Only user with this access rights (%s) are allowed to ....' % base_group.name)
```

don't forget to import exceptions:

```
 from openerp import exceptions
```

Comment: Thank you soo much! It worked for me!

Comment: you welcome my friend ^^

Comment: Is my question not clear??? :(

Comment: i edited your question you should always use little talk and try to put some code that you tried because this site is not for suggesting solution but for fixing code that is not worked i was blocked for 6 month see

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you so much :)